# SMBFS/CIFS - can't navigate to paths with spaces

Tags: server, samba

Using Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS, I recently upgraded to the latest samba and smbfs via apt-get, and when I mount our windows share via SMB, I'm getting this kind of error:

```
root@orbital testsmb/test# mkdir "spaces test"

root@orbital testsmb/test# ll
total 5
drwxr-xr-x  3 nobody nobody    0 Aug  4 17:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 37 nobody nobody    0 Aug  4 17:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x  0 nobody nobody 4096 Aug  4 17:32 spaces test

root@orbital testsmb/test# cd spaces\ test/
dirname: extra operand `test'
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
-su: [: =: unary operator expected
basename: missing operand
Try `basename --help' for more information.

root@orbital /spaces# pwd
/home/testsmb/test/spaces test
dirname: extra operand `test'
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
-su: [: =: unary operator expected
basename: missing operand
Try `basename --help' for more information.
```

Even using quotes, single and double, don't work:

```
root@orbital /spaces# cd ..
root@orbital testsmb/test# cd "spaces test"
dirname: extra operand `test'
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
-su: [: =: unary operator expected
basename: missing operand
Try `basename --help' for more information.

root@orbital /spaces# cd ..

root@orbital testsmb/test# cd 'spaces test'
dirname: extra operand `test'
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
-su: [: =: unary operator expected
basename: missing operand
Try `basename --help' for more information.
```

Here is my sanitized /etc/fstab:

```
//192.168.xx.xx/winshare      /home/testsmb  smbfs   rw,credentials=/etc/samba/winshare.creds,uid=nobody,gid=nobody,auto   0       0
```

- None of this happens on local file systems.
- Also an older SuSE box
  with an ancient smbfs doesn't run into these problems.

Comment: Err, what happens when you use tab complete to get there using cd? ie. `cd testsmb/test` then `cd spa<tab>`.

Comment: The tab completion as user606723 already stated is one of the hints i can think of. The other is whether you've you tried to mount a shared folder on another linux box and check if the problem remains.

Comment: Tab completion works fine for the first level of spaces (ie, cd 'spaces test' completes as cd spaces\ test/ ). But then further tab completion inside of that folder fails as if it has no content.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what is in `/etc/samba/winshare.creds`, and in `~/.bashrc`. Also the output of `type cd`.

Comment: enzotib, the creds file is one line with domain\user followed by one line with password.  Since I can actually see files on the share, I doubt it's a credentials issue. I can also reproduce this issue by directly mounting with credentials in `/etc/fstab` (which I prefer not to do). I can reproduce this problem with a newly added user (stock `.bashrc` for 10.04), so no user-modifications.   `type cd` returns "cd is a shell builtin"

Answer (score 1):

You have a broken alias setup for the cd command that is trying to do something involving `dirname` and `su`.  Fix or remove the broken alias.

Comment: Alias reports egrep, fgrep, grep, ls, ll, and penv-reload.  I unaliased the last two (as they're not stock) and I still have the same symptoms.   Also this doesn't happen on the local FS, only when I'm traversing space-embedded areas on an smbfs/cifs mounted drive.